# How to trap the focus for accessibility in mobile? (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, accessibility, focus

I want to trap the focus inside a modal in mobile device either iOS or Android.
Currently from the last element its focusing directly to the browser controls like home button or search bar. I want to focus from the last element to first element again.
Its working fine on Desktop with below code but not in mobile device.
https://hidde.blog/using-javascript-to-trap-focus-in-an-element/

For example,
[image: mobile web]

In below image from confirm button focus should traverse to close button. but currently its shifting to browser control i.e. address bar etc.

How we can trap the focus inside modal itself in mobile?
Can anyone suggest how it will work?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: You are talking mobile web, not mobile native app generated with React native or something? How are you steering focus on the mobile devices? Did you attach a keyboard or are you using VoiceOver and Talkback?

Comment: Yes, using mobile web and I am using javascript/ jQuery. Using talkback I am steering the focus.

Comment: have you considered to use instead the `inert` attribute for the nodes containing focusable elements that should be ignored while the modal is open? https://caniuse.com/?search=inert and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGLp_gfMMGU

Comment: HI @FabrizioCalderan, I have tried it using this way https://developer.chrome.com/articles/inert/. For both states true and false I am not able to access the div element.

Comment: Wow you are right. Bootstrap uses the same method of intercepting TAB in their modal dialog. I tested with Talkback and it does not at all trap focus.

Comment: <div id="maincontent">
 <div class="filter"></div>
 <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>

Onclick of .filter , .sidebar will be open which having css .sidebar {
 display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

Now Using JS

if (Mobile) {
 $('.sidebar').attr('inert', false);
} else {
 $('.sidebar').attr('inert', true);
}

Comment: [The ARIA Authoring Practices Guide’s dialog example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/dialog-modal/dialog.html) actually seems to intercept `focus` events on elements outside the dialog and then replaces focus on the first or last element inside the dialog.

Comment: <div class="side-bar " role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="filters-title" aria-describedby="result"> This way also its not working. After last element going to browser home button.

Comment: There’s an older question for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034319/how-to-respect-modal-dialog-trapzones-with-androids-talkback

Comment: @Bhagyashri please improve on your question by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself, not in the comments.